# Error: Arguments 2. 3, 4, 9 must be named, not unnamed. Trying to change a likert scale to numerical data, what am i doing wrong?

Tags: r

```
globalshare <- final_data %>%
select(`Share_1`, `Share_2`, `Share_3`, `Share_4`) %>%
unique() %>%
paste() %>% 
cat("Extremely likely" = 4, "Somewhat likely" = 3, "Neither likely nor unlikely" = 2, "Somewhat unlikely" = 1, "Extremely unlikely")

globalsharefinal <- c("Extremely likely" = 4, "Somewhat likely" = 3, "Neither likely nor unlikely" = 2, "Somewhat unlikely" = 1, "Extremely unlikely")
```

This data works correctly

```
global.recoded <-  final_data %>%
mutate(globalshare = recode(`Share_1`, `Share_2`, `Share_3`, `Share_4`, !!!globalsharefinal))
```

This is where it goes wrong. What in the code is going wrong?

I am very new to R, so please give me a dumb down breakdown!

Thanks

I have tried a code which i thought was correct but it is not working

Comment: Please consider including in your question a small subset of `final_data` by copy-pasting the output from running `dput(head(final_data))` so that we can help you. Ideally you'll also include the output you're expecting so we know what the end result should be.

Comment: Share_1 = c("Extremely unlikely", 
"Extremely unlikely", "Somewhat likely", "Somewhat likely", "Extremely unlikely", 
"Neither likely nor unlikely"), Recall_1 = c("in glasgow the crime rates are going up, burglers are targetting students with laptops",

Comment: Theres too many characters to add to it, I am trying to convert the extreme unlikely etc to numbers, with the final data set being the original piece of data.  globalsharefinal is where I have converted the scale from language to numbers. global share is where I have only included the columns from the participants answers to the sharing questions.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: As @Dubukay indicated, it would be helpful to provide some of your data in order to replicate the problem. Assuming that `final_data` is a data frame, you cannot use functions like `unique()` or `paste()` on it, because they are specifically for vectors (or variables) within a data frame. If you are looking to learn R, I would suggest this book to get you started: https://r4ds.had.co.nz/